# Persistent (casper-rw) Dropbox keeps prompting to reconnect

Tags: linux, linux-mint, live-usb, dropbox

I use Linux Mint as my main operating system, but I run it off a persistent casper-rw partition on a flash drive. (I don't want to install it to the disk because my laptop screen is broken, and if something went wrong I'd be hopeless to repair it because I can only see the screen after the OS loads. It's tricky enough to boot as it is, and I can't see what I'm doing in BIOS.)

The setup works like a charm, with one hiccup: my Dropbox installation (downloaded from the website) prompts to reconnect my account at login. The prompts are:

- Do you already have a Dropbox account? (*Yes*)
- Enter your username and password, and pick a name for this computer. (*I always pick "casper-rw"*)
- It looks like you've already set up Dropbox on this computer. Would you like to use the same settings? (*Yes*)
- You're done! (*Finish*)

Dropbox then starts up and works properly. It recognizes the existing `~/Dropbox` folder and syncing works fine.

This is pretty annoying, especially considering that I get confirmation emails every time I do this, and my Dropbox account currently shows about a dozen copies of the same machine "linked" to my account.

I've never had this issue on Mint on an actual install, though it may be worth noting that the last full Mint install I used was Mint 15, and I'm using Mint 16 on this LiveCD.

Is there any way I can get Dropbox to use my existing settings without a prompt?

---

Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64-bit. HP Elitebook 8440p. SanDisk Cruzer 16 GB flash drive with two 8 GB partitions, FAT32 `boot` and ext2 `casper-rw`.

Comment: From my experience the dropbox software is pretty buggy, your issue likely is with their software, and has nothing to do with Mint. I would look to try and resolve the issue focusing on just dropbox software.

Comment: @slm How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Most likely not here. I'd start searching the internet, also the dropbox software has a lot of undocumented switches and features, but you'll have to just mess with it. Check here: https://www.dropboxwiki.com/. Tips and tricks are also in the dropboxwiki: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks. As it stands your issue really has nothing to do with Unix or Linux though.